# Help in XML Parsing with iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing

I need to parse the xml listed below in the iphone. can anyone help me in this.
please...!

Thanks in advance...

```
<Assignments>
<Course>
    <CourseName>Foundation of English</CourseName>
    <CourseGradePercentage>89</CourseGradePercentage>
    <AssignmentList>
        <Assignment>
            <AssignmentName>Foundations of English I</AssignmentName>
            <Week>Week 1</Week>
            <AssignmentGrade>2</AssignmentGrade>
            <AssignmentGradePercentage>20</AssignmentGradePercentage>
        </Assignment>
        <Assignment>
            <AssignmentName>Foundations of Maths I</AssignmentName>
            <Week>Week 1</Week>
            <AssignmentGrade>2</AssignmentGrade>
            <AssignmentGradePercentage>20</AssignmentGradePercentage>
        </Assignment>
    </AssignmentList>
</Course>
<Course>
    <CourseName>Foundation of Maths</CourseName>
    <CourseGradePercentage>92</CourseGradePercentage>
    <AssignmentList>
        <Assignment>
            <AssignmentName>Foundations of English I</AssignmentName>
            <Week>Week 1</Week>
            <AssignmentGrade>4</AssignmentGrade>
            <AssignmentGradePercentage>40</AssignmentGradePercentage>
        </Assignment>
        <Assignment>
            <AssignmentName>Foundations of Maths I</AssignmentName>
            <Week>Week 1</Week>
            <AssignmentGrade>4</AssignmentGrade>
            <AssignmentGradePercentage>40</AssignmentGradePercentage>
        </Assignment>
    </AssignmentList>
</Course>
```

What i need to get is this..

### Foundation of English1      99.99%

Week1 Assignment          10 (100%)
Week2 Assignment           8 (80%)
Week3 Assignment          10 (100%)

### Foundation of Mathematics1    100%

Week1 Assignment          10 (100%)

This is just a sample data.. this is the format which i need to display on the iphone table view..
Please Help me..

Thanks,
Shibin
shibin.moideen@mediaus.com

Comment: You need to post you xml sample as a code block - in the example shown above all xml tags got stripped!

Comment: `CourseGradePercentage` should be `GradePercentage`. `AssignmentGradePercentage` should be `GradePercentage`. Notice that you can then reuse the same code for parsing. And <Week>Week 1</Week> is also redundant. You could just have <Week>1</Week>. Better yet would be <Assignment Week="1">.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `libxml2` with an Objective-C front provided by [this useful set of wrapper functions](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html).

You issue an XPath query to your XML document object and get back Foundation class objects: `NSArray`, `NSString`, and `NSDictionary`, e.g.:

```
//
// Generate NSData* object called _xmlData which is the XML data
// 

// ...

//
// Query this data for course names
//

NSArray *_queriedCourseNames = PerformXMLXPathQuery(_xmlData, @"//*[local-name()='Course']/*[local-name()='CourseName']");
```

Comment: ok thanks, but i cant understand this one. also i am using the NSXMLParser rather than libxml2

Comment: can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058694/getting-zero-objects-from-the-xml-file-in-the-array

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'Course,' why do you want to use local-name?

```
//Course/CourseName
```

should just work, right?