# iPhone SDK:How can I fix this leakage?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have a leakege here but couldnt find the problem;

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableData *responseXMLData;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableData *lastLoadedResponseXMLData;
```

[image]

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [doc release];
    doc=nil;
    [xmlBodyTemp release];
    [responseXMLData release] ;
    responseXMLData=nil;
    [lastLoadedResponseXMLData release];
    lastLoadedResponseXMLData=nil;
    [xmlBody release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing your `dealloc` method, we cannot be sure you are correctly releasing the values of these properties.

But in the posted code, I do see one major problem. But it's not where you think.

```
self.lastLoadedResponseXMLData = docTempData;
```

This line, although flagged by XCode, is fine (assuming you release the value correctly in `dealloc`).

```
self.responseXMLData = [self.lastLoadedResponseXMLData copy];
```

This line, however, is not fine. It makes a copy of whatever value is in `self.lastLoadedResponseXMLData` but you never release the reference due to the copy. `self.responseXMLData`, since it is declared "retain", adds its own reference to the object, and (assuming you release the value correctly in `dealloc`) this reference is the one cleaned up.

If you don't really need to care whether the object is the same or is a copy, just forgo the copy. Otherwise, autorelease it:

```
self.responseXMLData = [[self.lastLoadedResponseXMLData copy] autorelease];
```

Comment: i updated the code, IF lastLoadedResponseXMLData was not declared as "copy" in the properties. your suggestions are still same?

Comment: could you also look at tnx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007767/iphone-sdk-xml-mystery-after-adding-child-nodeforxpath-returns-nothing-found-a

Comment: @XDeveloper: If lastLoadedResponseXMLData were declared "retain" instead of "copy", the situation remains the same. If it were declared "assign" things would change.